# Can't get custom CSS file to load in Child theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I want to use a couple of custom css files for a page template in a child theme, but looking dev tools, I see that they are not being requested on page load. The header for the page-mp3-downloader looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset=utf-8>
    <title>Music Downloader App</title>
    <!-- =================  CSS Files  ================-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <?php wp_head() ?>
</head>
```

and the functions.php file is:

```
<?php
/* This enqueues the Parent style.css file for this child theme */
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'twentyseventeen-style'; // This is 'twentyseventeen-style' for the Twenty Seventeen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

/*=============  Code Added by Me ======================================- */

/* Code to enqueue(load) the custom.css file for sgt. peppers page */
function wpb_adding_styles() {
    if (is_page_template('page-sgt_peppers.php')) {
       wp_register_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css');
       wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css');
    }

    /* Load style sheets for MP3 Downloader page if  page requested */
    if (is_page('page-mp3-downloader.php')) {
       wp_register_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/reset-mp3.css');
       wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/reset-mp3.css');
       wp_register_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main-mp3.css');
       wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main-mp3.css');
   }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');
```

The css file for page-sgt_peppers.php loads fine in the child-theme root. But I tried both in the root and in /css/ for page-mp3-downloader but custom css files never get requested. I've read over WP codex on enqueueing but don't see what I'm missing. Here is my directory structure [image: child-theme]. Any help appreciated.

Update: 
Got css file to load by using:

```
/* Load style sheets for MP3 Downloader page if  page requested */
    if (is_page('mp3-downloader')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('wpsx-reset-mp3-style');
        wp_enqueue_style('wpsx-main-mp3-style');
    }
```

Am I right in assuming because mp3-downloader was not constructed from a template but just a file I modified from page.php that is_page() is the conditional tag to use?

Comment: Do you still have a template comment header in the page-sgt_pepper?  e.g <?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?> If so that is probably why the first if statement works.

The reason your updated code is working (`is_page('mp3-downloader')`) is because the argument you are passing to `is_page()` now matches the slug of the page you are targeting(as aposed to the file name.) See the doc for it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

**First:**

You are using `is_page_template()` on the "'page-sgt_peppers.php" enqueue then you use `is_page()` for "page-mp3-downloader.php".

You should use `is_page_template()` for both.

**Second:**

You are using [`wp_register_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) incorrectly. From the codex:

> A safe way to register a CSS style file for **later** use with
>   [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Note the "later use" part. The register script function allows you to call  `wp_enqueue_style($handle);` later on instead of listing paths and dependency over and over. You do not have to register them at all but it is good practice so I am keeping it in my suggested fix below.

You should also register them with unique handles. Codex:

> **$handle** (string) (required)Name of the stylesheet (which should be unique as it is used to identify the script in the whole system).

That said you can try the following:

```
<?php

/* This enqueues the Parent style.css file for this child theme */
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'twentyseventeen-style'; // This is 'twentyseventeen-style' for the Twenty Seventeen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
                      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
                      array( $parent_style ),
                      wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );

    /*Register styles for later use*/
    wp_register_style('wpsx-custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css');
    wp_register_style('wpsx-reset-mp3-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/reset-mp3.css');
    wp_register_style('wpsx-main-mp3-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main-mp3.css');



}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

/*=============  Code Added by Me ======================================- */

/* Code to enqueue(load) the custom.css file for sgt. peppers page */
function wpb_adding_styles() {
    if (is_page_template('page-sgt_peppers.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('wpsx-custom-style');
    }

    /* Load style sheets for MP3 Downloader page if  page requested */
    if (is_page_template('page-mp3-downloader.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('wpsx-reset-mp3-style');
        wp_enqueue_style('wpsx-main-mp3-style');
    }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');
```

Comment: I'm sorry but now I get neither css files for either page loading. I see you left out the paths.Are they needed. Also I should point out that these pages are not from templates but page.php files that I modified.

Comment: update: I was wrong sg-peppers loads ok but mp3-downloader still not requesting css files.

Comment: Yes thanks. I am a little confused because sgt-peppers was constructed using a template and then later in experimenting with custom pages I added page- to name and removed template from admin page but is_page_template still works for that page. I guess maybe something in database is not right.